What bug creature is hanging on the wall in the painting within Professor Fig's office?
When you enter Professor Fig's office, on the left, there's a bug creature painting:

It looks like some kind of mosquito, but I'm not sure. I haven't seen such a bug or creature anywhere else in the game yet.
What kind of bug creature is this?

It looks like a Billywig:

The Billywig was a magical insect native to Australia. It was rated XXX, and was around half an inch long and of a vivid sapphire blue colour. The speed of the Billywig may be why it was rarely noticed by Muggles, and wizards and witches often only spotted it once they had been stung.


